# Do you use triple class, when three classes together?

Tags: vocabulary

> "What have we got today?" Harry asked Ron as he poured sugar on his
>   porridge.
>
> "**Double** Potions with the Slytherins," said Ron. "Snape's Head of
>   Slytherin House. They say he always favors them –– we'll be able to
>   see if it's true."
>
> –– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

*Double* seems to mean two Houses together. When three houses together, do you use *triple class*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Double seems to mean two Houses together.

No, it refers to two hours of teaching.

Comment: I couldn't see how this can mean two house (or two houses). Isn't a potion the same thing as an elixir? (I guess that Double Potion here might refer to something that twice as strong as a typical potion.)

Comment: Not exactly. This is Hogwarts, after all, and "Potions" is a subject being taught there. If they had two hours' worth of Divination, they'd call it "Double Divination", no doubt.

Comment: It is not necessarily two *hours* of teaching. A school day is timetabled into specific periods (at least, my school called them periods... my daughter's school calls them blocks). I have known schools with 35-minute periods and others with periods over an hour. Most lessons will occupy one period, but there will be double periods for some subjects. I imagine the shorter the basic period/block, the more "doubles" there will be in the timetable.